# New Android Gradle plugin 1.3 feature of separate instrumentation test module not working

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, robotium, gradle-plugin

On running the instrumentation tests for module `test`, I'm getting the following error -

```
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError' Empty test suite.
```

I have a project with two modules : `app` and `test`

This is the `build.gradle`(test)`

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test'

    android{
        compileSdkVersion 19
        buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
        defaultConfig{
            testApplicationId 'com.xx.android.test'
            testInstrumentationRunner com.xx.android.test.CustomRunner'
        }
        targetProjectPath ':app'
        targetVariant 'debug'
    }
    dependencies {
        compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    }
```

& this is `AndroidManifest.xml` for test module

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.xx.android.test">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<application>
    <uses-library android:name="android.test.runner" />
</application>
    <instrumentation android:name=".CustomRunner"
        android:targetPackage="com.xx.android"
        android:handleProfiling="false"
        android:functionalTest="false"
        android:label="Instrumentation test"/>
</manifest>
```

Comment: is that file `AndroidManifest.xml` or `Manifest.xml`  The latter is incorrect

Comment: Yes it was a typo..Thanks JBirdVegas!

Comment: Was it fixed? If `no`, please try to upgrade for gradle plugin version